# Ubuntu keyboard layout inside VM is always opposite of my Windows Client

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have a few VMs running under VMWare ESXi  running on a HP DL380P g6 server.

I access my management network on IP 192.168.0.20 my client PC which runs windows 10.

The VMs themselves are headless and non-headless Ubuntu 18.04 and the UI language is English (UK), region is Belgium and input source is Belgian.

When I click on the keyboard layout button  (where? On the Windows PC?) the layout is showing `azerty` but when I type, `qwerty` comes out.

I figured that when using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> it changes the layout, but the problem is my Windows Client PC  changes from `azerty` to `qwerty` and my VM from `qwerty` to `azerty` so my PC is always the opposite of my VM.

*Any idea on how to change this behaviour?*

I tried `loadkeys`, `setxkbmap` already but no luck.

Comment: Please review [my edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1031004/revisions) to your question and clarify more clearly what the exact set-up is.  Click **[edit]**  to edit your question and clarify where the problem is located exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I could understand your question, but I use this:

dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

Comment: already tried no luck  but thankx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

owkey my pc was the problem. I had belgium french - changed to belgium period and it fixed my keyboard layout in the vm too. why everything is in english and my calendar still german I have no clue. But it's owkey for me tank you everyone for the help :)